# How to remove duplicates from a List of List using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

SCENARIO:

I have a text file, which I am reading and avoiding to add duplicate rows into a list, called `basket`.

PROBLEM:

The problem is that, the following logic avoids duplicate but does not add some rows like the rows with ID 4 and 1 are not added into the `basket` list.

QUESTION:

- Could someone please check what's wrong?
- Is there any better way to achieve the same thing?

(Text File: abc.txt)

```
ID  ITEM    QTY SOURCE
2   Banana  4   tree
3   Milk    3   animal
5   Creme   2   animal
2   Banana  4   tree
3   Milk    3   animal
10  Banana  4   tree
4   Milk    3   animal
5   Creme   2   animal
1   Banana  4   tree
32  Milk    3   animal
```

(Code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<string>> basket = new List<List<string>>();
            var filePath = @"c:\temp\abc.txt";
            using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                while (!stream.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var lineContents = stream.ReadLine().Split('\t');
                    if (!DuplicateItem(basket, lineContents))
                    {
                        basket.Add(lineContents.ToList());
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static bool DuplicateItem(List<List<string>> basket, string[] line)
        {
            return basket.Exists(row => row.Exists(col => col.ElementAt(0).ToString().Equals(line[0]))) ? true : false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what is the definition of *duplicate* in your case. For instance, is it based on "ID" column value only, or all the column values or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checking of existences of ID is invalid, as you are checking the first char of the ID of the row for equality with the string ID of the new line. (That's why to had also needed to use `ToString`). You can simplify your logic like:

```
private static bool DuplicateItem(List<List<string>> basket, string[] line)
{
    return basket.Exists(row => row[0] == line[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using List of List, why not just one List and check the duplicate from there? You can do this instead:

```
IList<string> basket = new List<string>();
```

Then on your while statement:

```
if (!basket.Contains(lineContents[0].ToString()))
basket.Add(lineContents[0].ToString());
```

No need to add the DuplicateItem static method.